# Show submenu with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my menu. I would like to show the submenu (in the last item) when I pass the mouse over the last item. I'm trying to do it with css only but it doesn't work. this is the code

```css
#submenu {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right:26px;
    background-color:#f1f3f5;
    width:21%;
}
#submenu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c5c9;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align:right;
}
#submenu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#submenu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#submenu li a {
    border-right: 0 !important;
    padding:5px 2px 0 0;
}
nav .last:hover > #submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" target="_self">First item</a>
    <a href="#" target="_self">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="last" target="_self">Third item
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>                                                       
    </a>
</nav>
```

Is it possibile to show/hide the submenu when I mouseover/mousout on the last nav item?

Comment: check this link :::::    http://codepen.io/lisa_c/pen/QwyoQq                                                      http://css-snippets.com/drop-down-navigation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#submenu { display:block; position:absolute;float:right;right:26px;background-color:#f1f3f5;width:21%;}
    #submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c5c9; padding: 5px 5px; text-align:right;}
    #submenu li:first-child { padding-top: 10px;}
    #submenu li:last-child { border-bottom: none;}
    #submenu li a {border-right: 0 !important;padding:5px 2px 0 0;}
    #submenu { display:none;}
 nav .parent:hover #submenu { display:block;}
```

```html
<html>
<nav>
    <a href="#" target="_self">First item</a>
    <a href="#" target="_self">Second item</a>
    <span class="parent">
 <a href="#" class="last" target="_self">Third item</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>                                                       
    </span>
</nav>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this:

```
nav a.last:hover+#submenu { display:block;}
```

Complete running example:

```css
#submenu {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right:26px;
    background-color:#f1f3f5;
    width:21%;
}
#submenu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c5c9;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align:right;
}
#submenu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#submenu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#submenu li a {
    border-right: 0 !important;
    padding:5px 2px 0 0;
}
nav .last:hover > #submenu {
    display:block;
}
nav a.last:hover+#submenu { display:block;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" target="_self">First item</a>
    <a href="#" target="_self">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="last" target="_self">Third item
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>                                                       
    </a>
</nav
```

Comment: Thank you, it workd perfectly. Would be possible to keep the submenu visible also when I pass the mouse over its items? Otherwise I cannot navigate thru it

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` can't be nested inside another `<a>`. You html should be like following.

```
<a href="#" class="last" target="_self">Third item</a>
<ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and css should be

```
nav .last:hover + #submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is not `<ul>` inside `<a>`, this is `<a>` inside `<a>`. Nested `<a>` elements are forbidden in HTML syntax. HTML specifications do not say why; they just emphasize the rule. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2